# Why Reap and Sow is not working here

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap

Here in the first example my code works:

```
Reap[
  For[x = 1, x <= 10, x++, 
    f[x];  
    Sow[{x, f[x]}]]][[2, 1]]`
```

and I can plot $x$ vs $f(x)$.

However, for a 3D plot this code doesn't work:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + 1 + y^2  
Reap[
  For[x = 1, x <= 10, x++,
    For[y = 1, y <= 10, y++,
      f[x, y];  
      Sow[{x, y, f[x, y]}]]]][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I missed `[[2,1]]`

Comment: Or `Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}], 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your question is really about `Reap` and `Sow`. Or perhaps it is about how to produce your list of points. If the latter, use `Array`:

```
Catenate@Array[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} &, {10, 10}]
```

**Edit:**

As Bob Hanlon suggested, one may also use `Table`.

```
xs = Range[10]
ys = Range[10]
Catenate@Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, xs}, {y, ys}]
```

Your `xs` and `ys` can be arbitrary lists, which adds some flexibility. This same functionality may be achieved with `Outer`:

```
Catenate@Outer[{#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} &, xs, ys]
```

In short, it is unlikely that use of `For`, `Sow`, and `Reap` are the best way towards your goal. Ordinarily, use `Sow` and `Reap` only when you don't know how many results you want to keep.

Comment: Yes in this simple example , I just wanted to evaluate the function for some range of x and y and plot. But I want to generalize this for complicated function that runs over the variables x and y and store the arrays in a single varaiable (A say) and plot.

Comment: @wahlang Then  you can use `Table`, as suggested by Bob Hanlon's comment. I'll add an example. If it doesn't meet your need, please explain.